# Get Current Live Streams for a List of Channel IDs (Youtube API)

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need to get the current live streams for a list of channelIds. After a lot of research it looks like the only solution is to use the search endpoint, specifying the channelId. This solution will not work because the very high unit cost (100 units per channel in the list). Additionally, I would be polling the live streams for this channel list every 5 minutes or so. This would be far too costly to work.

Potential Solutions:

1) Push Notifications API
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications

If this API could also send notifications for when a channel starts a live stream, this would completely solve my problem

2) Activities Endpoint
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list

If this endpoint would also include livestream activity, I could use this since the cost would only be 1 unit per channel, which could work.

3) Search Endpoint
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

If this endpoint could accept multiple channelIds, I could use a few search calls to get all of the channels, which might also work.

Are there any other ways to solve this problem? It seems like a pretty valid use case for the Youtube API to be able to get live streams for a channel without the extraordinary cost per channel.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I ended up just working around the problem. There is an undocumented/beta endpoint called `liveChatStatus` that handles this use case, but Youtube doesn't openly provide it.

Comment: I ended up using pubsubhubbub which does provide live stream information. Seems to work well

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to look into that. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: I had no luck with Pubsubhubbub. I would subscribe and it would be a success, but no alerts on my endpoint.